# Some questions about Vector in STL

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have some questions about vector in STL to clarify.....

1. Where are the objects in vector allocated? heap?
2. does vector have boundary check? If the index out of the boundary, what error will happen?
3. Why array is faster than vector?
4. Is there any case in which vector is not applicable but array is a must?

Comment: "Why array is faster than vector?" - Have you tried profiling the operation that you tried to compare? Because I think STL vector has been optimized such that the difference with array is very little or it is even faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In a contiguous memory block on the heap. A `vector<int>` allocates memory the same way `new int[x]` would.
2. Only if you use the `at` method. It throws an `std::out_of_range` exception if the boundary check fails. The `operator[]` doesn't perform bounds checking.
3. Because an array gives direct access to memory, while accessing a vector element most likely involves a method call. The difference can be ridiculously small though, especially if your compiler decides to inline the calls.
4. In general, you'll use a `vector` if you want your container to have a dynamic size, and a simple array if a known fixed size is enough. Be sure to check out the other containers, like `deque` and `list`, to be sure you pick the most appropriate one. Otherwise, if you need to deal with non-C++ APIs, you'll obviously need to have access to a regular array. (edit) @BillyONeal says you should use `&vector[0]` to get the address of the underlying array, but use it with care since it can change if the vector's capacity changes.

Comment: You can pass vectors to non C++ apis no problem. `&myVector[0]` is required to return a pointer to the vector's memory, and so long as the vector's size does not change, it must have the same underlying layout as a built in array.

Answer (score 0):

> Where are the objects in vector
>   allocated? heap?

It depends on the STL implementation, but in all likelihood on the heap, yes.

> ```
> does vector have boundary check? If the index out of the boundary, 
> what error will happen?
> ```

Yes, a vector grows dynamically, you can check its size using the `capacity()` member function. If it should run out of space, it generally allocates more space using the `reserve()` member function.

> Why array is faster than vector?

Arrays can be faster because they are plain data that does not need to be accessed through a wrapper object such as `vector.` You can think of a `vector` as neatly packaged array for your convenience.

> Is there any case in which vector is
>   not applicable but array is a must?

I think there can be times where an array is preferable over a `vector`. For example, when dealing with legacy C code or when speed is of utmost importance. But generally you can solve any array problem by containing the data in an STL `vector`.

Comment: "Arrays can be faster" <-- In theory, yes, but this will not be true on most modern compilers. You can also pass legacy API's the vector array with `&myVector[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Ad 4.: When dealing with legacy interfaces (e.g. POSIX) arrays may be a must.

Comment: Grr.. no, you can pass vector data to legacy interfaces. Just use `&myVector[0]`.

Comment: I have to admit: You are right, sorry! The space is guaranteed to be continous.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the heap (assuming you use the standard allocator, which is the default)
2. It is not boundary checked when using `operator[]`, but it is if you use the member function `at` (e.g. `my_vec.at(0)`). If you use `at` and the index is out or bounds, it throws an `std::out_of_range` exception.
3. Arrays aren't generally faster. It depends whether or not the vector's `operator[]` calls are inlined or not. Most modern compilers should index it though, as it is just a single array index.
4. In general, normal arrays can be replaced by vectors. You shouldn't really use a `std::vector` on the public interface of a library, and manu library APIs require raw C-style arrays.

Comment: "... raw C-style arrays ...". That's what `&myVector[0]` is for.

Comment: @Billy: Glad you're going around correcting everyone, but Poita worded his a little different and he's right.  &myVector[0] is good for the actual parameter but the formal parameter, which is the actual interface, is a raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

1. By default contents are allocated dynamically. (But I suppose you can provide an allocator that gets the memory from some place else.)
2. The `at` method does bounds checks and throws an `out_of_range`. Other methods may or may not check bounds, depending on implementation and settings.
3. I would assume a vector to be slower than an array when it does something different from an array. For example, dynamic allocation is costly, so vector has a cost that arrays don't have. Dynamically resizing a vector is costly, whereas an array can't be resized at all. I wouldn't expect to see any difference when accessing the elements (except for possible run-time checks done by the implementation which you should be able to turn off if desired).
4. I don't know of such a scenario. You can always get a pointer to the underlying array of a vector with `&vec[0]`. However, a vector can be an overkill if you don't need any of the features it provides - mostly the ability to (re)size it dynamically. In such cases an array could do just fine, but note that there are classes that make an array a first-class object too (`std::tr1::array` or `boost::array`) which make the array copyable and not decay into a pointer.